# Neo4j get match sum over a number of nodes

Tags: neo4j, count, sum, cypher

I've got a question that I've been struggling with.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to check if a certain sum can be found in a number of nodes.. for example.. i have account nodes with an attribute called balance. The data is as follows: 25, 2000, 43, 45, 2000, 65.

I want to be able to check if this user has exactly 4000 over 2 accounts (for example.. could be more).

Not sure if I explained myself well and I'm new to the cypher world.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by taking all combinations of account balances, summing both, and comparing.

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) is a plugin for Neo4j that adds many useful procedures and functions. One of them, `apoc.coll.combinations()`, can help in this case, but due to a bug it wasn't included in 3.3.0.1 or 3.3.0.2 (the releases currently usable for Neo4j 3.3.x).

If you're using 3.2.x, or when the next release of APOC 3.3.x.x comes out, you can use the function to generate all possible combinations of list elements.

Here's an example of use:

```
WITH [25, 2000, 43, 45, 2000, 65] as balances
WITH apoc.coll.combinations(balances, 2) as combos
RETURN [combo in combos WHERE combo[0] + combo[1] = 4000] as balancesSummingto4k
```

In your case, if you just want to check if a user's balances sum to a number, it may look something like this:

```
MATCH (:User{id:12345})-[:HAS_BALANCE]->(b:AccountBalance)
WITH apoc.coll.combinations(collect(b), 2) as combos
RETURN size([combo in combos WHERE combo[0].balance + combo[1].balance = 4000]) <> 0 as hasBalancesSummingTo4k
```

Comment: That's beautiful! Thanks!